# How to add Navigation bar to view controller with tab bar item

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, navigationbar

I have an app that uses bottom tabs aswell as a side menu, to have the button that initiates the side menu i use the typical three line menu button, to put that there I have a Navigation Bar. With the bar in place there is no way I can get the bar to be on top of the screen. I built it with interface builder, and heres a screenshot. The question is how do i have the navigation bar alone without the other grey bar above it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is due to the fact that you're manually creating a navigation bar for your view controller, instead of using the bar that you get for free by embedding the view controller in a tab bar controller, hence the reason you see two bars. The other answer suggesting hiding the auto-generated navigation bar is not the correct solution. Instead, you should place your menu button and view title in the auto-generated bar instead of manually creating your own (you almost never want to do that, in-fact).

So what you should do instead is set the `title` property of your view controller to be "News", and the `leftBarButtonItem` property of the view controller to be your hamburger menu button (an instance of `UIBarButtonItem` initialized with an image for the icon).

For example (inside your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method or wherever appropriate):

```
self.title = @"News";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuIcon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSideMenu)];
```

Comment: hello, I've  put the code in my viewdidload method and the button still hasnt showed up or responded to a click. heres the link to my view controller https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kqdjixj04xyx91/FirstViewController.m

Comment: Without seeing the entire project it's difficult to tell. For one, you need to set the `title` property on the view controller itself, not the tab bar controller. So it should be `self.title = @"News";`. As for the bar button, is the image you're using white? The `Plain` style might be causing it to display without a tint color, essentially making it invisible over the white navigation bar.

Comment: ok 2 things 1 how do i change the plain style, changing the color or removing the line doesnt work, and 2 how do i get that button to trigger the menu launch

Comment: For the button style, try using `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` instead (on iOS 7 it doesn't actually add a border). As for triggering an action when the button is tapped, just set the appropriate target and action in that same initialization line. In my above example, tapping the button would fire the method called `showSideMenu` on the view controller.

Comment: Actually I think I know why your image isn't being displayed, I made a typo in my original example- when using `imageNamed:` you don't include the file extension. So it should be `[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuIcon"];` (or whatever the name of your image is, without the extension). Sorry about that.

Comment: firstly, I genunely appreciate all your help. secondly nothing  i try works, you wouldnt happen to know how to do this via storyboard?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52634/discussion-between-blabus-and-user3381665)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the topmost navigation bar you need use `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` for view controllers that used for tabs in `UITabBarController`:

```
// StoriesViewController.m
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you, also do you know how to make the navigation bar taller?